# React Native error when I run this code in phone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is what I got when  ran the code in my mobile phone using expo

[image]

This is the code for the app

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Teext, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';`enter code here`

    const ComponentsScreen = () => {
    return <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Hello World! </Text>
    };
    const styles = StyleSheet.Create({
    textStyle: {
               fontsize: 30
          } 
    });
     export default ComponentsScreen;
```

This is the code that I ran and I don't know what the error is.

Comment: You have a problem with imports... I think `Text` is misspelled. Also, the error is missing from  the question

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Teext, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';`enter code here`
```

it should be `Text` not Teext and you need to wrap it into a View Parent

```
const ComponentsScreen = () => {
    return(
<View>
 <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Hello World! </Text>
</View>
)
    };
```

do this and Welcome To React Native !